# Swagger example attribute hiding all other attributes

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I'm writing a `Swagger` definition on [swaggerhub](https://swagger.io/tools/swaggerhub/). There's an option to share models among multiple Swaggers. After swaggers are complete there's an option to download resolved Swagger with the linked definitions imported.

My problem is that this resolved download adds a `example` node to the models which for whatever reason overrides every attribute when we copy this new Swagger in editor again.

Suppose we have following sample

```java
---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: ""
  version: 1.0.0
  title: title
host: "example.com"
basePath: /
schemes:
- http
consumes:
- application/json
produces:
- application/json
paths:
  /test-service:
    post:
      tags:
      - test-service
      operationId: test-service
      parameters:
      - in: body
        name: body
        description: body
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/A'
      responses:
        201:
          description: success
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/A'
definitions:
  A:
    type: object
    properties:
      a1:
        type: string
      a2:
        type: string
```

Following is how it's displayed in the `Swagger UI`,

This is correct way, however when I there's an example node in the model `A`, only example attributes are displayed in the UI,

[image: Correctly displayed]

Here's the change that that I'm referring to

```javascript
  A:
    type: object
    properties:
      a1:
        type: string
      a2:
        type: string
    example:
      ex1: Hello
      ex2: World
```

Now, if I import this change in the editor, only attributes `ex1` and `ex2` and actual attributes `a1` and `a2` are missing.

[image: Incorrectly displayed]

**Problem is exacerbate when we have inheritance.**

What happens is whichever lowest node in hierarchy has `example` attribute only attributes listed in that are shown in the UI, rather than showing all attributes

Here's a sample wi[image: Correctly displayed]

Now lets introduce `example` attribute in `C`. After addition of `example` attribute at any level all other attributes are ignored.

Here's the link to `example` attribute documentation https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/adding-examples/.

There's no description of this weird behavior.

[image: Incorrectly displayed]

Comment: The documentation you posted is for OpenAPI 3.0. The doc for 2.0 is https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/adding-examples/; the "Example Precedence" section explains (sort of) this behavior.

Comment: I will edit that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how `example` works. Quoting the [OpenAPI 2.0 Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#user-content-schemaExample):

> A free-form ... example of an instance for this schema.

That is, `example` is an example *for the entire schema*. That's why a schema-level `example` is displayed as is. It overrides any property-level examples, and won't automatically include properties that aren't included in the `example`.

In your last example with `allOf`, the schema for `A` is equivalent to

```yaml
definitions:
  A:
    type: object
    properties:
      a1:
        type: string
      a2:
        type: string
      b1:
        type: string
      b2:
        type: string
      c1:
        type: string
      c2:
        type: string
    example:
      ex1: Hello
      ex2: world
```

which again is why the schema-level `example` from `C` overrides everything else.

You might want to use property-level examples instead:

```yaml
definitions:
  A:
    type: object
    properties:
      a1:
        type: string
        example: Hello   # <---
      a2:
        type: string
        example: world   # <---
```

Comment: Problem is I don't have any control over the resolved download. I'm not using example node, but it's there when I download  using `Download YAML(Resolved)` option. Is there a way to stop this from happening in Swaggerhub?

Comment: Will "Download YAML (Unresolved)" work for you? "Resolved" is for specs that include external $refs (to domains, etc.).

Comment: That said, `example` being added automatically looks like a bug. I'd suggest that you [open a support ticket](https://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=SwaggerHub).

Comment: Thanks, I'm using external domains to share models among multiple swagger files, resolved is the only option. I have left a message on support chat, lets see.

Comment: @11thdimension The issue with unexpected `examples` in Resolved YAML seems to have been fixed now.